# objective-c determine if parameter is an object

Tags: objective-c, object, parameters, primitive

in Objective-c I have this function prototype:
-(NSString*)formatSQL:(NSString*) sql, ...
I may pass to this function any type of parameters: NSString, NSNumber, integer, float
How can I determine in the function if a parameter is an object (NSString..) or a primitive (integer...)?
thanks
BrochPirate

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to have a parameter that accepts multiple types, you can only safely do it by using Obj-C objects, which means using `id` as the type. You can't safely inter-mingle `id` with `float`, `integer` etc.

If you wrapped up all `float`s and `int`s in `NSNumber`s, you could have a method like so:

```
- (NSString *)formatSQL:(id)obj
{
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        // Format as a string
    }
    else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        // Further processing will be required to differentiate between ints and floats
    }
}
```

There are a few caveats to using `isKindOfClass:`, but this should serve as a good starting point.